# How do you represent nil in Go AST?

Tags: go, abstract-syntax-tree

Looking at the [Go AST documentation,](https://golang.org/pkg/go/ast/) I don't see any node type to represent a `nil` in the code.  BasicLit doesn't cover it in the list of token types it accepts, and in fact when I look at the source to `go/token` I don't see a `nil` token at all!

If I want to create an AST of the form `if x != nil`, how do I do the `nil`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the Go specification, `nil` is a predeclared **identifier**. Therefore, it is represented by [`*ast.Ident`](https://golang.org/pkg/go/ast/#Ident) in an AST:

```
node := ast.NewIdent("nil")
```